# How to solve cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: python, database, oracle

I get an error while trying to insert data into my oracle database with python. I already created a connection and a table in Oracle database.  Please how do i solve this error?

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from csv import writer
import cx_Oracle


conStr = 'system/Maxesafrica2@localhost:1521/orclXDB'
cnx = cx_Oracle.connect(conStr)        
cursor = cnx.cursor()

print("Connected to Database!")

cursor = cnx.cursor()

html_text = requests.get('https://www.jobberman.com/jobs/hospitality-leisure').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

jobs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'mx-5 md:mx-0 flex flex-wrap col-span-1 mb-5 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-300 hover:border-gray-400 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-gray-500')
     
salary_scale = ''
 
job_list = []
for job in jobs:
    company_name = job.find('p', class_ = 'text-sm text-brand-linked').get_text(strip=True)
    kills = job.find('p', class_ = 'text-lg font-medium break-words text-brand-linked').get_text(strip=True)
    job_desc = job.find('p', class_ = 'text-sm font-normal text-gray-700 md:text-gray-500 md:pl-5').get_text(strip=True)
    job_link = job.find("a", href=True)["href"]
    salary_scale1 = job.find('span', class_ = 'mr-1')
             
    if salary_scale1:
       salary_scale = salary_scale1.get_text(strip=True)
    else:
       salary_scale = 'Not Mentioned'

    all_details = (company_name, skills, job_desc, job_link, salary_scale)
    all_details = tuple(all_details)
    job_list.append(all_details)
     
       
    insert_query = """INSERT INTO jobberman_tbl (company_name, skills, job_desc, job_link, salary_scale)
                              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
                              
    records_to_insert = job_list         
      cnx = cx_Oracle.connect(conStr)


        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(insert_query, records_to_insert)  
               
 cnx.commit()
 cursor.close()
 cnx.close()

 print('Done!')
```

HERE'S THE ERROR I GET

File "c:\Users\LP\Documents\python\Oracle\oracle.py", line 90, in

cursor.executemany(insert_query, records_to_insert)

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: Constructs like `(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)` are a security risk, and a performance/scalability problem.  Please  use bind variable.  Please use `executemany()`.  Review https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html

Comment: @Christopher Jones thanks for your answer. I used `(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)` in place of the old construct and my code ran successfully but in the table in my oracle database, only the column names are displayed and no data is present in the columns.